# the node "mix shader" is not available

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

Im really new to blender, so please excuse me if its a stupid question. but im stuck and can't find anything similar to my problem:

When I hit shift A and try to find mix shader, its not available. the other nodes I need are there though.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: the Mix Shader should be part of the Shader list, if it's not the case maybe show a screenshot of your interface?

Comment: Hi :). Make sure you're in a Shader Editor and not the Compositor ;)

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for your replies :)) @moonboots Im in Shader Editor and Mix Shader is not part of the Shader list. 
here is a screenshot of my Interface: https://de.share-your-photo.com/7d29b291c7

Comment: @JachymMichal :)

Comment: You are editing the _World_ shader.  (See the globe in the upper right part of the shader window.  Switch back to the _Object_ shader by clicking on the globe and selecting world.

Comment: ahh thank you! @MartyFouts

Answer (score 4):

You are editing the *World Shader*

[image: image showing World shader being edited]

Recent versions of Blender only show shaders that are legitimate in the current world configuration and the mix shader is not, in the way you have the world shader set up.

Click on the "World" box and select "Object".

Answer (score 2):

The workbench render engine only has support for a limited set of shaders. Blender will hide shaders from the add menu that are not relevant for the currently selected render engine. You can switch the render engine from Workbench to either Eevee or Cycles in the `Properties Editor > Render Properties > Render Engine` and the mix shader should become available for use in the world shader.

[image]